# Why is Pathlib module not found in my venv?

Tags: python

I tried

```
>>> import Pathlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pathlib'
```

I checked from shell

```
pip install Pathlib
Requirement already satisfied: Pathlib in /Users/milenko/mario/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.1)
```

How it comes that I can not import this module?

Comment: Python is case sensitive - try `import pathlib`.

Comment: @БогданТуренко Yeah,works fine now.

Comment: if you're using PyCharm go ahead install that module through the settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python considers `Pathlib` and `pathlib` differently.try: `pip install pathlib` and `import pathlib`
if it doesn't work then try
`pip3 install pathlib`

Answer (score 0):

`pathlib` is part of the standard library for `Python 3.4+`.

In my case, I was using the old import line

```py
from Pathlib import Path
```

Solution

```
from pathlib import Path
```